# Add advance function ora:getFaultAsString() in XSLT transformation using Jdeveloper 12

Tags: oracle, xslt, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I'm using XSLT transformation but I can't add the advance function ora: getFaultAsString(). I created a variable and set a namespace on it, but still not working. I'm getting Function of Name "ora:getFaultAsString" not found.

I can add it using assign component but on XSLT I can't add it.

URI: http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension
Prefix: ora

Please let me know for any answer or solution to this. It will be a great help for me since I'm still new to SOA suite and Jdeveloper 12.

Thank you in advance!